# Capitalization of "das googlen (des eigenen Namens)"

Tags: capitalization, nominalization

The [FAZ writes](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/christian-wulff-was-es-heisst-ein-mann-zu-sein-11890516.html):

> So verstanden ist das Abrufen der Mails, das googlen des eigenen Namens und das Zählen von Followern und Freundschaftsanfragen nichts als eine Statusabfrage der eigenen Existenz.

Why is "das **g**ooglen" in lowercase, while "das **A**brufen" and "das **Z**ählen" are in uppercase?

Comment: The more common spelling is *googeln*, by the way.

Comment: It's simply wrong. The word "googlen" contains two errors: It is written in lowercase and the letter "l" should stand between "e" and "n": It should be "das Googeln".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because even the *Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung* can err. In my opinion it is definitely an error and should be capitalized.

Edit:
The concept involved is "Substantivierung (von Verben)" ("nominali[s/z]ation" in English). The [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung#Beispiele_f.C3.BCr_Substantivierung_.28im_Deutschen.29) has a short overview for this, the corresponding rule of the ["Amtliches Regelwerk" (PDF)](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) is §57.

Comment: Gibt es da nicht Abweichungen zw. alter u. neuer Schreibung, und hat die FAZ sich nicht zur alten Schreibung bekannt?

Comment: @userunknown Ich bin der Meinung, dass sich nur bei der Substantivierung von Adjektiven etc. Änderungen ergeben haben. Substantivierte Verben wurden schon immer groß geschrieben.